# how to connect other machine install Elastic search server?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm install  elastic search 0.16.2 on Debian Linux.I want to connect 
elastic server which is install Debian box. previously I install 
elastic server in my machine.for creating node i used following code:

```
 Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder() 
                                .put("index.number_of_shards",1) 
                                .build(); 
       Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder() 
                                .client(false).settings(settings) 
                                .local(false) 
                                .node().start();
```

Note: “local”meaning that local servers started within the same JVM 
will discover themselves and form a cluster.

Linux box IPAddress 192.168.1.100 where elastic server is 
install.where I do changes to connect Linux box elastic search server using 
java ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to connect via the transport client?

Then this should do it (not sure if you really need to specify the cluster):

```
Settings s = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", cluster).build();
TransportClient client = new TransportClient(s);
client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(url, port));
```

But be sure that ElasticSearch cannot be searched from the rest of the world :)